error TS2304: Cannot find name 'InputEvent' angular?
I have using anuglar/cli@8.3.22 with node version 13.14.0 when I try to build I got these error I'm stuck please any body help me with it.
    only.directive.d.ts(19,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'InputEvent'.
node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/lib/autocomplete-lib.module.d.ts(7,21): error TS2694: Namespace '"node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.
node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/lib/autocomplete-lib.module.d.ts(8,21): error TS2694: Namespace '"node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration'.
node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/lib/autocomplete-lib.module.d.ts(9,21): error TS2694: Namespace '"/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectorDeclaration'.
node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/lib/autocomplete.component.d.ts(243,21): error TS2694: Namespace '"/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.
node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/lib/autocomplete.component.d.ts(244,21): error TS2694: Namespace '"node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration'.
node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/lib/highlight.pipe.d.ts(5,21): error TS2694: Namespace '"node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.
node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/lib/highlight.pipe.d.ts(6,22): error TS2694: Namespace '"node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵPipeDeclaration'.


there are two type of errors
here is screenshot for it


You probably need to take a look at the compatible versions of Angular and NodeJS:
https://www.redcricket.net/en/news-en/compatibility-list-for-angular-angular-cli-and-node-js/

but I've already match the versions.

did you remove your node_modules folder and reinstall the dependencies?
npm ci

yes I've reinstall ,remove cache and done many things including ci. but not got exact solution

then I would look into compatibility of your dependencies with angular and TypeScript:

The library that contains only.directive.d.ts
angular-ng-autocomplete


also I've facing  ng-auto-complete problem in error message.
